# Is it possible to write a gis application with c++(using mfc or windows forms)

Tags: winforms, gis

I am trying to write a program that reads a `gis` file, shows the map.(like country road map) with zoom and etc... And is able to calculate the road distance between every point I choose on map and a specific other point.

I hope that I have explained it right.. I have searched a lot and the more I search(maybe for some library to help) more confused I get..
I know (some) c++ language. And have worked with MFC and Windows Form application.

I even don't know is it possible to do that with my knowledge or not and if no: what is the best place, way or library to use?

Answer (score 0):

The open source GIS [QGIS](http://qgis.org) is written in C++ but the UI is based on Qt. Maybe it still fits your bill. It's possible to write stand-alone applications which use the QGIS API and it provides map rendering as well as routing (for your road distance computations).